# Contar en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Necesito hacer un conteo y no logro dar con ello, mi problema es el siguiente: tengo 5 días de la semana donde los empleados seleccionan el menú que comerán cada día; por lo regular son 4 menús diferentes por día.
la tabla donde se guardan los registros tiene la estructura siguiente:

||Fecha || clave_trabajador || semana || year || id_menu ||

Tengo una sentencia que me dice cuantos menús 1 se entregaron en la semana, pero necesito sacar el conteo por día.

esta es la sentencia por semana.

```
SELECT
  id_menu, count(id_menu)
FROM
  menu_usuario
Where
  semana =46 AND ano = 2019
GROUP BY
id_menu HAVING count(id_menu)>1;
```

No logro hacer el conteo por día.

Comment: Añade a tu descripción de la tabla un par de registros de prueba para ver en qué formato está la fecha. Indica además el tipo de cada columna en la tabla (algo va de usar un varchar a un date o algo así)

Answer (score 3):

Si el problema es: ***obtener la cantidad de menúes 1 por día,*** y entendiendo que el menú 1 es aquel dónde `id_menu = 1`, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
select fecha, 
       count(id_menu)
       from menu_usuario
       Where semana = 46 
             and ano = 2019
             and id_menu = 1
       group by fecha;
```

Comment: muchas gracias, resolví el problema con php, anidando consultas. sin embargo me queda la duda si se puede hacer solo con MYSQL, Lo que me propones es correcto pero los únicos valores que debe ingresar el usuario son la semana y el año por lo tanto la sentencia debería de regresarme los totales por día de todos los menús de la semana.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con un DISTINCT.

SELECT
  id_menu, count( DISTINCT id_menu)
FROM
  menu_usuario
Where
  semana =46 AND ano = 2019
GROUP BY
id_menu;

Comenta

Comment: Recuerda que responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad, editar y explicar cómo esto soluciona el problema haría más fácil verificar

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda lo probare así.